# Show an image only while uploading (xhr.addEventListener)

Tags: javascript, html, image, upload, addeventlistener

Im trying to show an image while an upload is happening, and remove it when the upload is complete.

I have managed to get the image to display, although when the upload is complete the image stays there.  how can I remove it once its done.

```
xhr: function() {
  var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
  //Upload progress
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
      var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
      console.log(percentComplete * 100 + '%');
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<img src='spinner.gif' alt='img' />";
    }
  }, false);
  return xhr;
},
```

live example: http://codepen.io/DrCustUmz/pen/KzZOeP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your ajax success function:

```
success: function(result) {
   document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "";
    //other code
     };
```

Comment: *facepalm* thanks still learning js but i should of known this lol

Comment: Glad I could help!